# Where can I see "include first row as header" in MSysIMEXSpecs?

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-excel, ms-access-2010

As stated in this post:

[How to List Field's Name in table in Access Using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548697/how-to-list-fields-name-in-table-in-access-using-sql/11553147#11553147)

you can use the system tables called MSysIMEXSpecs and MSysIMEXColumns to alter an import or export definition in Access.

However when I use the export guide I can set **"include first row as header"** to yes, but I cannot find that setting in MSysIMEXSpecs and MSysIMEXColumns afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Found another solution:

When you call the **DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim** function in your VBA code, you simply add a "True" in the [HasFieldNames] position of the code.

Like this:

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "ExportDefinitionName", _
    "t_Receive_Transactions_LastImport_AllFiles", "Q:\t_Receive_Transactions_LastImport_AllFiles.csv", True