# List of all fields in respective tables

Tags: list, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I was trying to get a list of all the fields in all the tables in Access 2007. I tried a bunch of macro suggestions I found, but none of them worked, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try http://superuser.com/questions/436893/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-fields-and-respective-tables-used-in-an-ms-access-2010-d and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548697/how-to-list-fields-name-in-table-in-access-using-sql and http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/07/09/how-can-i-list-all-the-fields-and-data-types-in-an-access-database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could make a DAO-Connection to CurrentDb and Loop through the TableDefs-Object to get all tables. The use the Fields-Collection.