# MS Access 07-10, want to be able to put fields into a list / combo box

Tags: ms-access, search, vba

Just wanted to know how you can put column headings (fields) in MS access  into a list box or drop down to make a multi-search form for 'n' number of fields.

colour | texture | <- fields

red.......smooth
blue ....rough

I wanna have drop down where i can put colour and texture in a list box and select them and then search against them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548697/how-to-list-fields-name-in-table-in-access-using-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access 07-10, want to make a filter for the column headings using a Macro or VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893456/ms-access-07-10-want-to-make-a-filter-for-the-column-headings-using-a-macro-or)

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/11548697/… is an unnecessarily complex way to achieve what @user8807264 is trying to do with the combo box, but useful in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple now in Access 2007 and later. (I don't remember how to do it in XP and earlier.)

Create your combobox on a form, set the **Row Source** to your table and select "Field List" as the **Row Source Type**. That's all. The table field names will show in your combo box.

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to have multiple combo boxes as field lists and have them search against information within the fields ? like if i have three fields, i select two of them and search against them into a text box ? thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Are you asking, can I build a SQL string/query based on the contents of the combo boxes?

Comment: Yes, but as a field list, I want have a field list, from that list, click on fields and put it into a listbox, from that listbox hit a button that says search or run query, which will then show a query with those specified field's data sets and from there be able to search against that data set using another form or query search.