# Need button on form to insert field names of a table into another table in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

There are similar questions and answers on here, but I am such a VBA beginner that I don't have the ability to make changes to a code to make it work for me. Ideally this is what I need to create in an Access database.

1. On a form there is a text field that has a table name in it.
2. A pressed button inserts that table and its field names into a separate table (call it TableFields for ease, with columns "TableName" and "FieldName").

Is this possible? If this is answered elsewhere, can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

It seems like this post is similar, but not specific/dumbed down enough for me:
[How to List Field's Name in table in Access Using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548697/how-to-list-fields-name-in-table-in-access-using-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combobox or listbox that lists tables.

Code in button Click or combobox AfterUpdate event like:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database, x As Integer
If Not IsNull(Me.cbxTable) Then
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [" & Me.cbxTable & "] WHERE ID=0")
    For x = 0 to rst.Fields.Count - 1
        db.Execute "INSERT INTO TableFields(TableName, FieldName) " & _
                   "VALUES('" & Me.cbxTable & "','" & rst(x).Name & "')"
    Next
End If
```

Alternative code.

```
Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset, rst2 As DAO.Recordset, x As Integer
If Not IsNull(Me.cbxTable) Then
    Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [" & Me.cbxTable & "] WHERE ID=0")
    Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TableFields WHERE ID=0")
    For x = 0 to rst1.Fields.Count - 1
        rst2.AddNew
        rst2!TableName = Me.cbxTable
        rst2!FieldName = rst1(x).Name
        rst2.Update
    Next
End If
```